# Selenium on Python not connecting to any browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

I recently wanted to start making an application involving Selenium on Python. Whenever I initialize the web driver and run the code, it lingers for 30 seconds before throwing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<redacted>/PycharmProjects/NewApp/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser = Safari()
  File "/Users/<redacted>/PycharmProjects/Interpreter/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/safari/webdriver.py", line 57, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/<redacted>/PycharmProjects/Interpreter/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 104, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /usr/bin/safaridriver
```

The trace above says Safari, but I've also tried Chrome and gotten the same error. This trace comes from the simple code block:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Safari

browser = Safari()
```

I've done my fair amount of troubleshooting, but nothing seems to alleviate this problem. I checked that safaridriver is in the proper directory, and it is. I tried the command `safaridriver --enable` in my terminal, but to no avail. I've confirmed that I have "Allow Remote Automation" turned on in Safari.

Here are the relevant specs in case that helps:

- Operating system: macOS Catalina 10.15.4
- Python version: 3.8
- Safari version: 13.1 (15609.1.20.111.8)
- safaridriver version: Included with Safari 13.1 (15609.1.20.111.8)
- Selenium version: 3.141.0

Selenium was working like a charm while I was learning it, so I'm not sure what would have changed.

Answer (score 0):

From my previous experience this means that you Selenium is not able to find the proper driver to use for a given browser. What I suggest you is either to find the location of the driver on your Mac or to download it again and then give the path to the driver as argument to the Safari() constructor.